# TypeError: str object is not an iterator

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator, generator

I have a file consisting of words, one word on each line. The file looks like this:

```
aaa
bob
fff
err
ddd
fff
err
```

I want to count the frequency of the pair of words which occur one after the other.

For example,

```
aaa,bob: 1
bob,fff:1
fff,err:2
```

and so on.
 I have tried this

```
f=open(file,'r')
content=f.readlines()
f.close()
dic={}
it=iter(content)
for line in content:
    print line, next(line);
    dic.update({[line,next(line)]: 1})
```

I got the error:

```
TypeError: str object is not an iterator
```

I then tried using an iterator:

```
it=iter(content)
for x in it:
    print x, next(x);
```

Got the same error again. 
Please help!

Comment: What do you think `next(thing)` does? It doesn't mean "the thing that comes after `thing`".

Comment: Aside: One solution is: `pprint.pprint(collections.Counter(zip(content[0:],content[1:])).most_common())`

Comment: @user2357112 : Thats what i thought next was! What does next do? The python doc says: 'Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its next() method. If default is given, it is returned if the iterator is exhausted, otherwise StopIteration is raised.

Comment: @rowana: Did you see how the argument is called "iterator"? It takes an iterator as an argument, not one of the elements retrieved from the iterator, and it retrieves the iterator's next item. (This advances the state of the iterator, so the next `next` call or `for` iteration for that iterator will go to the item after that.) I suppose the next question is, what do you think an iterator is? `line` is not an iterator.

Comment: @user2357112,  Got it now! Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to keep track of the previous line, a file object returns it own iterator so you don't need the *iter*  or *readlines* at all, call *next* once at the very start to creating a variable *prev* then just keep updating  *prev* in the loop:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)

with open("in.txt") as f:
    prev = next(f).strip()
    for line in map(str.strip,f): # python2 use itertools.imap
        d[prev, line] += 1
        prev = line
```

Which would give you:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {('aaa', 'bob'): 1, ('fff', 'err'): 2, ('err', 'ddd'): 1, ('bob', 'fff'): 1, ('ddd', 'fff'): 1})
```

Comment: This is a great example of how to use an iterator. Think of `next` kind of like `[].pop()`: it returns the next value but also removes it from the iterator. One great use of that is a pseudo-reduce like this: get the initial value, then loop over the rest.

Answer (score 6):

`line`, like all `strs`, is an iter**able**, which means it has an `__iter__` method. But `next` works with iter**ators**, which have a `__next__` method (in Python 2 it's a `next` method). When the interpreter executes `next(line)`, it attempts to call `line.__next__`. Since `line` does not have a `__next__` method it raises `TypeError: str object is not an iterator`.

Since `line` is an iter**able** and has an `__iter__` method, we can set `it = iter(line)`. `it` is an iter**ator** with a `__next__` method, and `next(it)` returns the next character in `line`. But you are looking for the next line in the file, so try something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dic = defaultdict(int)
with open('file.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for i in range(len(content) - 1):
        key = content[i].rstrip() + ',' + content[i+1].rstrip()
        dic[key] += 1

for k,v in dic.items():
    print(k,':',v)
```

**Output** (*file.txt* as in OP)

```
err,ddd : 1
ddd,fff : 1
aaa,bob : 1
fff,err : 2
bob,fff : 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import Counter
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
result = Counter((a, b) for a, b in zip(content[0:-1], content[1:]))
```

That will be a dictionary whose keys are the line pairs (in order) and whose values are the number of times that pair occurred.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, **line** is a string and thus cannot be used with the **next()** method. Also you can't use a list as a key for the dictionary because they are hashable. You can use a tuple instead.
A simple solution:

```
f=open(file,'r')
content=f.readlines()
f.close()

dic={}

for i in range(len(content)-1):
    print(content[i], content[i+1])
    try:
        dic[(content[i], content[i+1])] += 1
    except KeyError:
        dic[(content[i], content[i+1])] = 1
```

Also notice that by using **readlines()** you also keep the '\n' of each line. You might want to strip it off first:

```
    content = []
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            content.append(line.strip('\n'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 2 line [deque](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.deque) and a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter, deque

lc=Counter()
d=deque(maxlen=2)
with open(fn) as f:
    d.append(next(f))
    for line in f:
        d.append(line)
        lc+=Counter(["{},{}".format(*[e.rstrip() for e in d])])

>>> lc
Counter({'fff,err': 2, 'ddd,fff': 1, 'bob,fff': 1, 'aaa,bob': 1, 'err,ddd': 1})
```

You can also use a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/uA0oG2/1) with a capturing look ahead:

```
with open(fn) as f:
    lc=Counter((m.group(1)+','+m.group(2),) for m in re.finditer(r"(\w+)\n(?=(\w+))", f.read()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your value `x` holds a string 'ddd/ccc/etc'. it has not next. `next()` belongs to the iterator and it used to get next element from the iterator. The correct way to call it is `it.next()`

```
it=iter(content)
for x in it:
    print x, it.next();
```

But you will get an exception after you finish to consume all elements in the iterator. So, you need to catch StopIteration exception.

```
for x in it:
    try:
        line, next_line = x, it.next()
        # do your count logic overhere
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

`dic.update({[line,next_line]: 1})` does not work. You will skip possible combinations.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `next(it)`?

Comment: @levi, Thank you. It worked perfectly. Sadly I don't have enough credits to up vote. When I do, I will!

Comment: I think you mean `it.__next__()` :)

Comment: @CraigBurgler not, next(). Test it.

Comment: Interesting, it's `it.next()` in Python 2 and `it.__next__()` in Python 3

Comment: This iteration is not conducive to incrementing all `line,next_line()` pairs. It basically skips every other count.  With this code incrementing the count for `line,next_line` is straightforward, but how do we increment the count for `next_line,next_next_line`.

Comment: @CraigBurgler not, It consumes all elements two by two. Because the for also executes .next()

Comment: Yes, which is why it skips every other count ... unless you implement some elaborate counting logic.

Comment: @CraigBurgler not it doesn't. Did you tried ? copy the code and test it.

Comment: I did try and found that simple counting logic would skip every other count. Please edit the code with the counting logic that would work with iterating two by two. I propose that whatever logic you implement will be more complicated than logic used to count with single iterations.

Comment: @CraigBurgler I tried and worked perfectly. Using content = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]. It prints every element.

Comment: Yes but we are not trying to print every element. From the OP, we are trying to "count the frequency of the pair of words which occur one after the other".

Comment: @CraigBurgler The OP wanted to know why the iterator was not working. In fact, he commented that my code worked just fine. I also added a comment " #do your counting logic here". The problem for him was getting current and next line from the iterator.

Comment: I agree your code is instructive as it demonstrates advancing the iteration from within the body of a `for` loop. Hopefully the OP can post his working code so we can see the counting logic he used with your two-by-two iteration.

Comment: The code now produces a `KeyError` when it attempts to increment the value of a key that does not yet exist

Comment: @CraigBurgler I got it what u said. I fixed. Check it.

Comment: That still doesn't solve the problem. When you call `next` on an iterator, it consumes the next value, so the `for` loop will never see that value. You are still going to skip half the lines.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, you can't use `next` on a line which is an string. You can use `itertools.tee` to create two independent iterator from your file object, then use `collections.Counter` and `zip` to create a counter object from the pairs of lines

```
from itertools import tee
from collections import Counter
with open('test.txt') as f:
    # f = (line.rstrip() for line in f) # if you don't want the trailing new lines 
    f, ne = tee(f)
    next(ne)
    print(Counter(zip(f, ne)))
```

note that since file object is contain the lines with new-line at their trailing, if you don't want that you can strip the lines.